# Warning: Attempt to present <Assessnow.GetTestViewController> on <UINavigationController> while a presentation is in progress

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I want to know the behaviour of navigation controller because I searched so many things and tried but didn't get the stack of navigation controller.  I am little bit confuse in pop and present and push to navigation controller.

So what I am doing is showing another ViewController:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

and I am coming from that view to again to my HomeViewController:

```
 _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

I am trying to open another ViewController:

```
let getTestViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GetTestViewController") as! GetTestViewController
    getTestViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    getTestViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    self.navigationController?.present(getTestViewController, animated: true, completion: nil).
```

But I am getting this warning:

```
"Warning: Attempt to present <Assessnow.GetTestViewController> on <UINavigationController> while a presentation is in progress".
```

I saw this below Links and tried but didn't reached.

[Attempt to present UIViewController while a presentation is in progress!-Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460224/attempt-to-present-uiviewcontroller-while-a-presentation-is-in-progress-warning).

[ios7 - Warning: Attempt to present UINavigationController on UINavigationController while a presentation is in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386613/ios7-warning-attempt-to-present-uinavigationcontroller-on-uinavigationcontrol).

I want to know why I am getting this warning and how can I resolve it.